# Features of Dependency Properties in windows 8 Store App

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-store-apps

Hello every one i am not sure about the Features of Dependency Properties in windows 8 Store App. For this i read this article but i can't clear. Can any one help me to clear me what is not the features Dependency Properties in windows 8 Store App in this list Thanks.

1. Dependency properties provide facilities to compute a given property's value based on several inputs.
2. Dependency properties can notify about changes in their values.
3. A callback handler can be assigned, so that whenever the property is changed, the callback handler will be invoked.
4. Dependency properties can have a default value through metadata.
5. None of the above.

Article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/dependency-properties-overview

Answer (score 0):

All the features from 1 to 4 apply to Windows 8 Store app.

Besides, I think you'd better read this article written by @Jeremey Likness: **[Dependency Properties in XAML for Windows 8 Apps](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1960912)** .